# Java Injection from one war file to another

Tags: java, dependency-injection, weblogic

I started developing project where weblogic is used as webserver. In this project, we have several war files merged into one ear file. Now, I need some functionality (dao access) from one war file in another waqr file. Is it possible to use EJB or java Injection to get an instance of dao object from one war fle in second war file?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to move the dao access classes up into the EAR file where both web modules will have visibility of the classes.

Individual web modules (war files) each get their own class loader and are unable to see each other's classes.